# Php connect to postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost   dbname=mydbname   user=myuser    password=mypass") or die(pg_last_error());
```

returns `Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host  "::1 ...",`

What I must do?

P.S. In file `php.ini` modul `extension php_pgsql.dll` is enabled

Comment: What does your `pg_hba.conf` file contain?

Comment: I dont know, this is remote server.

Comment: How can you use `host=localhost` then?

Comment: When use mysql (on remote server), as host value we can use `host=localhost` right? In postgresql this can not do?

Comment: If it's a remote server you can't be using host=localhost, no matter what database software you're using. (Unless you have an extremely oddly configured server!) Localhost means the server you are running your script on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Unable+to+connect+to+PostgreSQL+server%3A+FATAL%3A+no+pg_hba.conf+entry+for+host+%3A%3A1%22&aq=f) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unable%20to%20connect%20to%20PostgreSQL%20server%3A%20FATAL%3A%20no%20pg_hba.conf%20entry%20for%20host%20%3A%3A1) would've helped you determine the nature of the problem.

It looks like you're trying to connect over IPv6 (hence `::1`) and the host's `pg_hba.conf` doesn't have a rule allowing you to connect from the IPv6 loopback address (`::1`) as user `myuser` to database `mypass`.

I suspect the server is misconfigured; to work around it try specifying the host as `127.0.0.1` (the IPv4 loopback address) instead of `localhost`, or just omit the `host=` completely to use unix domain sockets if PHP supports that.

Your statement *"When use mysql (on remote server), as host value we can use host=localhost right?"* is completely nonsensical for both MySQL and PostgreSQL. If it's a remote server then it is by definition not on localhost. At a wild guess I think you might be trying to say that the server is remote in the sense that it's not the computer you are working on, but it's local *to the program you are running* because you are running the program on the remote server (by editing it on the remote server, uploading the program text over FTP, or whatever).